# Hardlinks of a file

Tags: linux, hardlink

What is, on Linux, the way to get a list of a file's hardlinks ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find /partition_root -samefile /partition_root/file/to/find/hardlinks/of
```

Answer (score 6):

Start by ensuring that the hardlink count from `ls` is more than 0.

If so, then you can search for them, somewhat painstakingly:

```
find <path> -type f -samefile <source>
```

This finds all files in a given path and compares the inode number of your source file against that of the found file(s). Hardlinks share the same inode. So if they match you have yourself a hardlink.

Answer (score 3):

There may be an easier/quicker method but

```
stat file
```

which gives something similar to

```
  File: `file'
  Size: 14              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 4227594     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  501/   phone)   Gid: (  501/   phone)
Access: 2009-09-22 15:33:15.000000000 +0100
Modify: 2009-05-11 17:01:15.000000000 +0100
Change: 2009-05-11 17:05:09.000000000 +0100
```

then using the inode number from the Inode line,

```
find /path -inum 4227594
```

Comment: Sorry, your answer is not clear. Inode is the same for all hardlinks?

Comment: great ! ( ls -i could do instead of stat )

Answer (score 0):

For hardlinks only:

```
find -samefile xaa -ls
```

to also include symlinks:

```
find -L -samefile xaa -exec ls -li {} \;
```

Using `-exec ls` here instead of `-ls` shows the owner, group, permissions and target of the symlinks themselves instead of the information of the target.